# Receive notifications when a component of a given type is activated by the router

Tags: angular, angular-router

I'm implementing an Angular Material 7 application in which I want the side menu to be removed when the user navigates to a particular part of the navigation hierarchy to display a DashboardComponent. When this happens, the URL is of the form: /site/{sitename}/dashboard[/{optionalpagename}]

One way I've tried is as follows, and it works when navigating within the application but not when going directly to the dashboard via an external link or pasting the URL into the browser:

```js
ngOnInit(){
    this.router.events
      .pipe(
        filter(event=> event instanceof ActivationEnd && (event as ActivationEnd).snapshot.component != null  ),
        map((event:ActivationEnd)=>{
          let component = event.snapshot.component;
          return typeof event.snapshot.component === 'string' ? component : (component as any).name;
        }),
        untilDestroyed(this)
      )
      .subscribe((s: string) => {
        switch (s) {
          case 'DashboardComponent':
            console.log('Hiding main menu');
            this.hideMainMenu = true;
            break;
          case 'SiteComponent':
          case 'AboutComponent':
          case 'HomeComponent':
          case 'LoginComponent':
            console.log('Showing main menu');
            this.hideMainMenu = false;
            break;
        }
      });
}
```

I do have a working solution which I'll post as an answer below but I'm not completely happy with it as it feels fragile.

This seems like a fairly common use case so I'm wondering if I'm missing a cleaner way of achieving this?

Answer (score 0):

Here is my working solution. I don't particularly like it as it will break if the URL schema changes. But maybe I'm being picky.

```js
  private ngOnInit()
  {
    let regex = new RegExp("/site/[a-z0-9_]+/dashboard");
    this.router.events
      .pipe(
        filter(event=> event instanceof ActivationEnd || event instanceof RouteConfigLoadEnd ),      
        untilDestroyed(this)
      )
      .subscribe((s: any) => {
        console.log("current url:",this.router.url);
        this.hideMainMenu = regex.test(this.router.url);
        console.log("hideMainMenu", this.hideMainMenu);
      });
  }
```